# What is the permalink or URL for a 404 page in WordPress?

Tags: http-status-code-404, permalinks

I am trying to validate the HTML on my 404 page for a WordPress theme, but obviously, the validator cannot find the page, because it doesn't exist.

http://cambridgeuplighting.com/agsdfachgsd

http://cambridgeuplighting.com/404a234

Or any false link will generate the 404 page, but what's the actual url for this page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most systems don't expose a 404 error page with a 200 status code. Tick the **Validate error pages** option at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options instead.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one, really. Your best bet is:

- find the bit in Wordpress which sets the 404 header and comment it out. (I gave it a quick go, but failed)
- If you're using firefox, install this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249 which will validate the page inside the browser. (This seems to be the same kind of thing for Chrome, but I haven't tried it: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo )
- download the pure HTML for the page and upload it.